# How to make validation response as json when using request class

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.8

I have these request file to register a new customer, I want to be the response json when the validation fails, how can I do that?

This is the request class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Validations;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;


class RegisterCustomerRequest extends Request
{

public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|min:3|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:customers',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'agree' => 'required',
    ];
}
}
```

And the registration function:

```
public function register(RegisterCustomerRequest $request)
{
    $customer = Customer::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
        'accepts_marketing' => $request->subscribe,
        'verification_token' => Str::random(40),
        'active' => 0,
    ]);

    // Sent email address verification notich to customer
    $customer->notify(new EmailVerificationNotification($customer));

    $customer->generateToken();

    event(new Registered($customer));

    return new CustomerResource($customer);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `RegisterCustomerRequest`  you can override default method `failedValidation` as below

```
 protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {

        if ($this->ajax()){

            throw new HttpResponseException($this->respondWithError(419,'VALIDATION_ERROR',$validator->errors()));
        } else{
            throw (new ValidationException($validator))
                ->errorBag($this->errorBag)
                ->redirectTo($this->getRedirectUrl());
        }


    }
```

also you can write your own response inside  `$this->ajax()` like below

```
if ($this->ajax()){
     return response()->json($validator->errors(),419);
}
```